# Threshold for psychometric experiment with three (or more) possible choices

Tags: probability, experiment-design, psychometrics, threshold

I'm running an experiment where subjects are viewing a stimulus, and they have to decide if the stimulus is brighter/darker/identical in respect to a standard image.
Stimulus luminosity actually varies, and it can be brighter, darker or identical to the standard. What i' triyng to estimate is the threshold (or the just noticeable difference) needed to correctly identify (let's say 75% of times) the stimulus as darker or brighter then the standard. I prefer to run the experiment with the method of constant stimuli, randomizing the standard luminosity.

From dummy data, I suppose that the plot of probability of response will follow the graph here showed. On Y-axis the probability; on X-axis the luminosity of the stimulus (-7 is darker, +7 is brighter, 0 is identical luminosity).
The red curve identify the probability of answering "darker"; the green curve the probability of answering "brighter", and the blue line the probability of answering "identical luminosity".

[image]

How can I consider an experiment like this? What is the correct model of analysis?
From google-searches I've found that it could be considered a "multinomial ordered logit model", but I'm not sure. And by the way, I was not able to find how to determinate the threshold or the JND in experiments like that.

Any references are welcome.

Comment: I suppose you know this, but the most common method of psychometric threshold estimation is a two-alternative forced choice procedure (in your case "brighter"/"darker"). For these you can easily use any variant of single- or double-staircase procedures. By varying the number of steps up and down for correct or incorrect responses and the respective step size, the procedure will converge on a desired threshold (e.g. 80%).

Comment: See [Garcı́c´a-Pérez (1998)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698997003404), his more recent work, and [Kaernbach (1991)](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/emotion/team/kaernbach/publications/1991a_kae_p%26p.pdf) for more details. Of course there are also other approaches such as [Baysesian staircase estimation](http://booksandjournals.brillonline.com/content/journals/10.1163/156856807780421174) procedures.

For more than two options maybe item response theory-models are be an option. But I'm not too familiar with this class of models.